# How to display one image at the time from images array which are fetched from database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

In this application I'm uploading images to my local uploads folder and in `MySQL database` I'm storing the image's name. How can I display one image at the time from images array which are fetched from `database`? Currently I managed to display all uploaded images using `EJS`. How can i set it that the single displayed image "src" changes every 10 seconds or so?

```
<% for(i=0; i<images.length; i++) { %>
    <img src="/uploads/<%= images[i].name %>" alt="">
<% }; %>
```

Comment: do you want to show only 1 image? which first or last?

Comment: @Yogendra I want to display only 1 image at the time, but I want to loop through all of them

Comment: I am not aware about EJS but I try to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much aware about EJS so if there is any syntax error change it at your end. First create a unique id for all images and same class name.

```
<% for(i=0; i<images.length; i++) { %>
    <% if(i == 0) { %>
        <img class="allImage" src="/uploads/<%= images[i].name %>" alt="" id="image_<%= i %>">
    <% }; %>
    <% if(i != 0) { %>
        <img class="allImage" src="/uploads/<%= images[i].name %>" alt="" image_id="test<%= i %>" style="display:none;">
    <% }; %>
<% }; %>
```

You can make if-else condition or use if inside style tag.

Now you need to define a javascript global variable. Value of that variable start from 0.

```
var a = 0;
```

Create a function and call it after every 10 seconds

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    myFuction();
}, 10000);
```

Check the length of images so when last image display we can start again with 0.

```
myFuction(){
    a = a + 1; // increment global variable to show next image
    var length = $('.allImage').length;
    if(length == a || length > a){
        a = 0;
    }
    $('.allImage').hide(); // First hide all image with same class
    $('#image_'+a).show(); //  Show next image
}
```

Hope this will help you to get your output. This work for me in php so I hope this will also work for you. If any syntax error, change it at your end. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used EJS before, but I imagine something using [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) since you have a rough time in which you want the image to change. 
Here's an example: https://repl.it/@johnoro/Image-shuffling-example
If you want it to loop without randomness, then you'll just want to keep an index instead.
I went ahead and added a link to version without randomness as well. Since EJS is just JavaScript, I assume this should be easy to convert for your purposes. Let me know if you need any more help!

And, for the purposes of showing the code without having to head over to another site:

```
// Selects the DOM node with the unique id, 'switch'.
const img = document.querySelector('#switch');

const images = [
    "https://picsum.photos/350",
    "https://picsum.photos/300?blur",
    "https://picsum.photos/300?grayscale&blur=2"
];

function changeImage() {
    // This'll give us a floating point number that's between 0 and the length of the images.
    const rand = Math.random() * images.length;
    // This'll give us an integer between 0 and the last index of our images.
    const index = Math.floor(rand);

    img.src = images[index];

    // Notice that the function calls itself with our desired time, in this case 5000 milliseconds, or 5 seconds.
    setTimeout(changeImage, 5000);
}

// We have to call it for the first change!
setTimeout(changeImage, 5000);
```

Comment: Seeing the other answer now, setInterval might be better so that you don't have to call setTimeout in the function (although this is simulating that). I think this way's pretty straightforward regardless.